# Issue with a circuit in Multisim V14.0

Tags: oscillator, cmos, multisim, multivibrator

I have a part of this circuit on a PCB working with a frequency of 1 Hz (I tested it with an oscilloscope; it works perfectly).

I have to change it to 2 Hz, so I tried to do that in Multisim V14.0, and I see 185 MHz. Same values, same everything, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: one of these cannot be true ... `change it to 2 Hz` and `Same values, same everything`

Comment: Change the timebase on the scope.